# Volume of a solid in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $E$ be the solid region bounded by two surfaces, $z=10-r^2$ and $z=2+r^2$ in cylindrical coordinates. I computed the volume a lot of times using cylindrical coordinates and got $\frac{64\pi}{3}$. But the answer said $16\pi$. Which one is correct?

Comment: $16\pi$ is correct. I suspect you miss "$\color{red}{r}\,dr\,d\phi$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use back usual cartesian coordinates (to understand, perhaps, better your solid), so you surfaces are the ("going down") paraboloid $\;z=10-x^2-y^2\;$ and the ("going up") paraboloid $\;z=2+x^2+y^2\;$.

These two "bowls" meet at the circle $\;10-x^2-y^2=2+x^2+y^2\implies x^2+y^2=4\;$, so projecting onto the plane $\;z=0\;$, we get that the volume is

$$V=\int_{-2}^2dx\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dy\left((10-x^2-y^2-(2+x^2+y^2)\right)$$

If the above is what you did, in whatever coordinates, then you shall get the correct answer. Now, the above in cylindrical coordinates is

$$\int_0^2dr\int_0^{2\pi}\overbrace{r}^{\text{jacobian}}(10-r^2-(2+r^2))d\theta=\left.2\pi\int_0^2r(8-2r^2)dr=-\frac\pi4(8-2r^2)^2\right|_0^2=16\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

Use cylindrical coordinates to evaluate the volume integral,

$$V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 [(10-r^2)-(2+r^2)]rdrd\theta$$
$$=2\pi\int_0^2(8r-2r^3)dr=16\pi$$